# splitting comma separated dataset into separate arrays

Tags: c#

I have a .csv file I'd like to modify. Here is the format of the file:

```
  Id, UTMGridEast, UTMGridNorth, LocDate, LocTime, Species
```

What I have done already is create an arraylist of all these values, but what I would like to do is create an arraylist of all the values and each line in the dataset is another array. This is because I need to edit the fields `UTMGridEast` and `UTMGridNorth` and then reinsert them into the arraylist.

My GUI consists of just two buttons, here is my code so far:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private string _filename;

    private string[] _splitValues;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

private void btnLoad_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Configure open file dialog box
        Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
        dlg.FileName = "Dataset"; // Default file name
        dlg.DefaultExt = ".txt"; // Default file extension
        dlg.Filter = "Commar Seperated Values (.csv)|*.csv" ; // Filter files by extension 

        // Show open file dialog box
        Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();

        // Process open file dialog box results 
        if (result == true)
        {
            // Open document 
            _filename = dlg.FileName;
            txtFilePath.Text = _filename;
        }
    }

    private void btnConvert_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ConvertToLatLong();
    }

    private void ConvertToLatLong()
    {
        string textFile = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(_filename);

        foreach (var value in textFile)
        {
            _splitValues = textFile.Split(',');
            Console.WriteLine("Split values: " + _splitValues[value]); 
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly I would split the text based on NewLine, as to get the individual lines, and then based on the field seperator.

something like

```
List<string> lines = new List<string>(textFile.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None));
for (int iLine = 0; iLine < lines.Count; iLine++)
{
    List<string> values = new List<string>(lines[iLine].Split(new[] {","}, StringSplitOptions.None));
        for (int iValue = 0; iValue < values.Count; iValue++)
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Line {0} Value {1} : {2}", iLine, iValue, values[iValue]));
}
```

But as I have always said, rolling your own CSV parser is very difficult.

Have a look at [Comma-separated values](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values)

Specifically at the section **Basic rules and examples**

What I would recomend is [C# Tutorial - Using The Built In OLEDB CSV Parser](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-using-the-built-in-oledb-csv-parser)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am still a little confused though! Using your code example, I have added the line `Console.WriteLine("VALUES: "+values);` to check if the values are correct, but I receive `VALUES: System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]` over and over again. Is this correct?

Comment: @DommyCastles, have a look at the Edited example. This sould output each value seperately.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what type `_splitValues` is, but assuming a `List<String[]>` will work:

```
private void ConvertToLatLong()
{
    var lines = from line in System.IO.File.ReadLines("foo")
                let splitLine = line.Split(',')
                select splitLine.Select(x => x.Trim()).ToArray();
    _splitValues = lines.ToList();
}
```

Comment: I have tried this and I receive errors stating that `The type arguments for method 'IEnumerable<TResult> System.Linq.Enumerable.Select<TSource,TResult>)' cannot be inferred from the query` Could you please elaborate on how to use this? Thank you!